# Python: Subtracting time from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I know there has been a lot of questions regarding this problem but none of the solution I'm able to implement which is super frustrating so asking.

I have a column of datetime such as:

```
time                      timezone
2015-03-10 18:20:27       Eastern Time
2015-04-14 21:22:15       Pacific Time
2015-04-10 18:03:10       Mountain Time
```

I want to subtract 3 hours from the `Pacific Time` and 2 hours from the `Mountain Time` and keep Eastern time as is.

My solution:

```
df_slice["Time"] = df_slice["time"].map(lambda x: x.time().isoformat())

fmt = "%H:%M%:%S"
def tz_adjust(row):
    if row["timezone"] == "Pacific Time":
        return row["Time"] - datetime.datetime.strptime("03:00:00",fmt)
    elif row["timezone"] == "Mountain Time":
        return row["Time"] - datetime.datetime.strptime("02:00:00",fmt)
    else:
        return row["Time"]

df_slice["Tz_Time"] = df_slice.apply(tz_adjust,axis=1)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: ("':' is a bad directive in format '%H:%M%:%S'", 'occurred
>   at index 1261660')

I also tried converting `time` to time using `.time()` and then subtracting hours based on the timezones, I get

> Operand "-" error for datetime.time() and datetime.time()

What is the simple solution for the task? It seems to be fairly easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#timedelta-objects) to subtract hours from datetime.

```
def tz_adjust(row):
    if row["timezone"] == "Pacific Time":
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(row["Time"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
    elif row["timezone"] == "Mountain Time":
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(row["Time"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
    else:
        return row["Time"]
```